# Force Spans to Wrap In Inline-Block Parent

Tags: css, overflow, whitespace, word-wrap, word-break

I'm writing an app where I wrap individual characters in spans to better handle click events. The characters are in a div with `display: inline-block`. How do I get the text to wrap? I've tried:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

as well as

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

to no avail. As you can see, it works on normal text, but not on text wrapped in spans.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/hugiqohawi/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score -1):

Set a width for your `div` elements. The `span`s will wrap at this point.

For a fluid width, use `100%`:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `word-wrap` in CSS.